# jQuery filter with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid which I need to filter by 2 different properties. Location & Language.

I've created an array of checked elements for each property and need to be able to filter the results by these.

https://codepen.io/lee-grant/pen/bGWzRYJ?editors=1111

```
  var filterActive;

    function filterCategory(cat1, cat2) {
        // Create an Array.
        var location = new Array();

        $('.location input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
            location.push(this.value);
        });

        if (location.length > 0) {
            console.log('Location values: ', location);
        }

        // Create an Array.
        var language = new Array();

        $('.language input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
            language.push(this.value);
        });

        if (language.length > 0) {
            console.log('Language values: ', language);
        }

        // reset results list
        $('.team-member').removeClass('active');

        // the filtering in action for all criteria
        var selector = '.team-member';
        if ($('.location input').is(':checked')) {
            selector = '[data-location*="' + location + '"]';
        }
        if ($('.language input').is(':checked')) {
            selector = selector + '[data-language*="' + language + '"]';
        }

        //show all results
        $(selector).addClass('active');
    }

    // start by showing all items
    $('.team-member').addClass('active');

    // call the filtering function when selects are changed
    $('.test :checkbox').change(function () {
        filterCategory(
            $('.location :checkbox:checked').val(),
            $('.language :checkbox:checked').val()
        );
    });
```

In the example it only works for 1 Location and 1 Language at a time; could anybody advise on how to get this to work correctly with multiple selections?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this way will solve your problem :

```
// 01 - get all location selected
// 02 - get all language selected
// 03 - filtering and show card by option selected
```

filtering code

```
   // 01 - get all location selected
   let locationSelected = $('.location input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function () {
      return $(this).val()
   }).get()

   // 02 - get all language selected
  let languageSelected = $('.language input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function () {
      return $(this).val()
  }).get()
    

    // filtering
    $('.team-member').each(function(){
      let $card = $(this)
      let dataLocation = $(this).data('location');
      let dataLanguage = $(this).data('language');
      
      // show card by location selection
      locationSelected.forEach(function(item, index){
        if( dataLocation.indexOf(item) !== -1 ) {
          $card.addClass('active');
        }
      })
      
      // show card by language selection
      languageSelected.forEach(function(item, index){
        if( dataLanguage.indexOf(item) !== -1 ) {
          $card.addClass('active');
        }
      })
      
    })
```

demo jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ymxf5oz1/

Comment: there is an update in the indexOf check section

Comment: Please tick (accept) if the answer can help you, so others will know if it is the answer your problem

Answer (score 0):

1 way you can do it is by looping over each of the array values, and add it like this:

```
if ($('.location input').is(':checked')) {
  $.each(location, function(i, x) {
    selector += '[data-location*="' + x + '"]';
  })
}
```

**Demo**

```js
(function($) {
  'use strict';

  var filterActive;

  function filterCategory(cat1, cat2) {
    // Create an Array.
    var location = new Array();

    $('.location input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
      location.push(this.value);
    });

    // Create an Array.
    var language = new Array();

    $('.language input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
      language.push(this.value);
    });

    // reset results list
    $('.team-member').removeClass('active');

    // the filtering in action for all criteria
    var selector = '.team-member';
    if ($('.location input').is(':checked')) {
      $.each(location, function(i, x) {
        selector += '[data-location*="' + x + '"]';
      })
    }
    if ($('.language input').is(':checked')) {
      $.each(language, function(i, x) {
        selector += '[data-language*="' + x + '"]';
      })
    }
    //show all results
    $(selector).addClass('active');
  }

  // start by showing all items
  $('.team-member').addClass('active');

  // call the filtering function when selects are changed
  $('.test :checkbox').change(function() {
    filterCategory(
      $('.location :checkbox:checked').val(),
      $('.language :checkbox:checked').val()
    );
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.team-wrap {
  margin: 0 -15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.team-wrap .team-member {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.team-wrap .team-member.active {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

.team-wrap .team-member header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.team-wrap .team-member header .view {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #3d3253;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
  padding: 13px 25px 13px 25px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(50px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(50px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(50px);
  -o-transform: translateY(50px);
}

.team-wrap .team-member header:hover .view {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
}

.team-wrap .team-member header .view:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3d3253;
}

.team-wrap .team-member header img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.team-wrap .team-member .content {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #e7d8d3;
  text-align: center;
}

.team-wrap .team-member .content h4 {
  color: #3d3253;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.team-wrap .team-member .content p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <ul class="location">
    <li><strong>Location:</strong></li>
    <li><input id="brighton" name="brighton" type="checkbox" value="brighton"><label>Brighton (1)</label></li>
    <li><input id="covent-garden" name="covent-garden" type="checkbox" value="covent-garden"><label>Covent Garden (6)</label></li>
    <li><input id="fitzrovia" name="fitzrovia" type="checkbox" value="fitzrovia"><label>Fitzrovia (8)</label></li>
    <li><input id="oxford-circus" name="oxford-circus" type="checkbox" value="oxford-circus"><label>Oxford Circus (12)</label></li>
    <li><input id="soho" name="soho" type="checkbox" value="soho"><label>Soho (6)</label></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="language">
    <li><strong>Language</strong></li>
    <li><input id="croatian-serbian" name="croatian-serbian" type="checkbox" value="croatian-serbian"><label>Croatian/Serbian (2)</label></li>
    <li><input id="english" name="english" type="checkbox" value="english"><label>English (21)</label></li>
    <li><input id="greek" name="greek" type="checkbox" value="greek"><label>Greek (5)</label></li>
    <li><input id="italian" name="italian" type="checkbox" value="italian"><label>Italian (13)</label></li>
    <li><input id="mandarin" name="mandarin" type="checkbox" value="mandarin"><label>Mandarin (7)</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="team-wrap">
  <article class="team-member" data-language="english italian" data-location="covent-garden">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Location: Covent Garden</p>
      <p>Language: English, Italian</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="team-member" data-language="croatian-serbian english" data-location="oxford-circus">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Location: Oxford Circus</p>
      <p>Language: Croatian/Serbian, English</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="team-member" data-language="italian" data-location="covent-garden">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Location: Covent Garden</p>
      <p>Language: Italian</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="team-member active" data-language="english mandarin" data-location="soho">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Location: Soho</p>
      <p>Language: English, Mandarin</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="team-member" data-language="english" data-location="fitzrovia">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Location: Fitzrovia</p>
      <p>Language: English</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="team-member" data-language="croatian-serbian greek" data-location="fitzrovia">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Location: Fitzrovia</p>
      <p>Language: Croatian/Serbian, Greek</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="team-member" data-language="english" data-location="fitzrovia">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Location: Fitzrovia</p>
      <p>Language: English</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="team-member" data-language="english" data-location="oxford-circus">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Location: Oxford Circus</p>
      <p>Language: English</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="team-member" data-language="english" data-location="oxford-circus">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Location: Oxford Circus</p>
      <p>Language: English</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="team-member" data-language="english" data-location="brighton covent-garden">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Location: Brighton, Covent Garden</p>
      <p>Language: English</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add pagination in this demo?

Comment: @jaydeeppatel It would be, but then the answer would not match the question. You sould start a new question

Comment: Hi @carsten thank you for your reply can you give me hint for the same ?

Comment: @jaydeeppatel As i said, You should create a new question. Remember to inlcude the code and what you have tried.